# ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx "npm -v" returns a different version

Tags: node.js, npm, ssh

ssh root@xxx "**npm -v**"

```
6.14.4
```

When i go to the server xxx as user root and enter the command **npm -v**

```
7.21.1
```

Why does this happen if the users are the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below list of commands seems to fix the problem

```
n=$(which node); \
n=${n%/bin/node}; \
chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; \
sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
```